# How to add navigation buttons(previous and next) to a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created image thumbnail and linked that thumbnail using the following code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  
</head>
<body>

  <!--thumbnail section-->
  <section class="container">
   <div class="row add-bottom text-center">
    <a href="#migrant" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
     <img src=".." alt="Project Image" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="#water" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
     <img src=".." alt="Project Image1" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </a>
   </div>
  </section>
  
  <!--Modal Content-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="migrant" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      
      <h3>Migrants</h3>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-footer txt_center">
       <p>
        <img src=".." alt="migrant01" class="pull-right">The Grapes of Wrath is an Amer list novel written by John Steinbeck and published in 1939. The book won the National Book Award and Pulitzer Prize for fiction, and it was cited prominently when Steinbeck was awarded the Nobel Prize in 1962
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="water" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Water</h3>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-footer txt_center">
       <p>
        <img src=".." alt="water01" class="pull-right">The Orchidaceae are a diverse and widespread family of flowering plants, with blooms that are often colourful and often fragrant, commonly known as the orchid family. Along with the Asteraceae, they are one of the two largest families of flowering
         plants. The Orchidaceae have about 27,800 currently accepted species, distributed in about 880 genera
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to add navigation buttons(previous and next) to the modal window which will display the image along with a paragraph which describes the image.
So that once the modal window is displayed I don't have to close the window and go back to thumbnail image over and over again. Once, the modal window is displayed by adding the navigation button I want to go for the desired image with its description.
How possibly could I go for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the javascript modal API to hide the current modal and show wathever you want.

For example, I associated a function to the buttons of the modals to do it:

```
<body>

  <!--thumbnail section-->
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row add-bottom text-center">
      <a href="#migrant" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src=".." alt="Project Image" class="img-responsive center-block">
      </a>
      <br />
      <br />
      <a href="#water" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src=".." alt="Project Image1" class="img-responsive center-block">
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--Modal Content-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="migrant" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <h3>Migrants</h3>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="modal-footer txt_center">
            <p>
              <img src=".." alt="migrant01" class="pull-right">The Grapes of Wrath is an Amer list novel written by John Steinbeck and published in 1939. The book won the National Book Award and Pulitzer Prize for fiction, and it was cited prominently
              when Steinbeck was awarded the Nobel Prize in 1962
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal('water')">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="water" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>Water</h3>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="modal-footer txt_center">
            <p>
              <img src=".." alt="water01" class="pull-right">The Orchidaceae are a diverse and widespread family of flowering plants, with blooms that are often colourful and often fragrant, commonly known as the orchid family. Along with the Asteraceae,
              they are one of the two largest families of flowering plants. The Orchidaceae have about 27,800 currently accepted species, distributed in about 880 genera
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal('migrant')">Previous</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    function showModal(id) {
      $(".modal").modal('hide');
      $("#" + id).modal();
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vegdyf48/

The javascript API:
    https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript

Comment: How to implement the same for multiple no of thumbnails?

Comment: Use the example function "showModal" as callback in `onclick` event on the buttons and pass the id of the thumbnail that you want to show.

Comment: This way the code will be very long and for multiple number of thumbnails it will be difficult to implement. So, I want to put the thumbnails in an array.How would I implement this one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how comfortable you are with jQuery, but you can accomplish this with a little bit of Javascript/jQuery. The best way would be to start with your images and text in some type of data object. Here is a Plunker link with an example based on your original code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Fq9pFzrgE9VOOLmljlXw?p=preview

In it, I've created a dataset using a basic array of Javascript objects.

```
var data = [
    { src: "https://placehold.it/150x150?text=Image1", title: "Image 1", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a est mauris. Sed non sollicitudin lacus. Sed maximus facilisis purus, et blandit lectus vehicula in." },
    { src: "https://placehold.it/150x150?text=Image2", title: "Image 2", description: "Aenean accumsan metus ipsum, id vehicula felis semper sed. Sed hendrerit pulvinar porttitor. Etiam id tortor leo. Integer ex dui, vulputate vel iaculis sit amet, laoreet eu sem." },
    { src: "https://placehold.it/150x150?text=Image3", title: "Image 3", description: "Vivamus luctus est at sapien sollicitudin, nec mattis arcu condimentum. Vivamus sed varius diam. Nulla varius, tortor vel tempus feugiat, libero felis pellentesque mi, sit amet sagittis lacus massa et erat. " },
    { src: "https://placehold.it/150x150?text=Image4", title: "Image 4", description: "Vestibulum eu ex ac nunc pretium hendrerit vel in quam. Morbi imperdiet imperdiet pharetra." }
  ];
```

Then, I created a few simple functions to manage the modal navigation, including a check to see if the nav links should be disabled. I'm also using the javascript trigger to open the modal, so you can load the appropriate item on click.

```
var currentItem = 0;

function prevImg() {
  if (currentItem > 0) {
    currentItem--;
  }
  loadData();
}

function nextImg() {
  if (currentItem < data.length - 1) {
    currentItem++;
  }
  loadData();
}

function loadData() {
  $("#modalTitle").html(data[currentItem].title);
  $("#modalImg").attr("src", data[currentItem].src).attr("alt", data[currentItem].title);
  $("#modalText").html(data[currentItem].description);

  // enable/disable nav buttons  
  $("#navPrev").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("#navNext").removeAttr("disabled");

  if (currentItem == 0) {
    $("#navPrev").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  else if (currentItem == data.length - 1) {
    $("#navNext").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
}

function openModal(idx) {
  currentItem = idx;
  loadData();
  $("#modal").modal();
}
```

To load the data, I looped through the dataset and appended the HTML for the thumbnails. This is a tad more complex, but still not terrible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $thumbs = $(".thumbnails");

  // dynamically add thumbnails to page
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $thumbs.append('<a href="#" onclick="openModal(' + i + ')" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" alt="' + data[i].title + '"><img src="' + data[i].src + '" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>');
  }
});
```

With that, you can reduce your HTML to using just one modal dialog. I've also included the nav links within the body, instead of using buttons in the footer.

```
<body>
  <!--thumbnail section-->
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row add-bottom text-center thumbnails">
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--Modal Content-->
  <div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <a id="navPrev" href="#" onclick="prevImg()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
              <img id="modalImg" src="" alt="" class="pull-right" />
              <span id="modalText"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <a id="navNext" href="#" onclick="nextImg()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Lastly, here are a few simple styles to format the nav links.

```
#navPrev, #navNext {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#navPrev:hover, #navNext:hover {
  color: red;
}

#navPrev[disabled], #navNext[disabled] {
  color: #cdcdcd;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried the above code but I am getting some undesirable result (multiple no of thumbnails and modals are being displayed at a time) which is no way same as the result being displayed in Plunker.Moreover, in Plunker also I have seen for the specified thumbnail corresponding modal is not being displayed, instead it is showing the 1st modal by default. I also want to dismiss previous/next button when it reaches to first/last modal. Instead of having buttons in the modal-footer how to use navigation arrows in the modal-body, which will in turn redirect to previous/next modal?

Comment: I've updated the answer to add the other features and fix the issue where it always showed the first item on click. If you use the code as-is, it will work. I would definitely recommend that you look for a few courses online to help you understand jQuery and Bootstrap a little better.